# Convergence to meromorphic function on open subset

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm working an exercise which states:

> Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ be open and nonempty. Consider a series $
> \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} f_n$ of meromorphic functions
>   $f_n$ on $U$. Assume this series is compactly convergent in $U$. Show that there exists a unique
>   meromorphic function $f$ on $U$ with the following property:
>
> *For $V \subset U$ open and $m$ such that for each $n \geq m$ the function $f_n$ has no poles in $V$ , the series
>   $\sum^\infty_
> {n=m} f_n |V$ of holomorphic functions on V converges compactly in $V$ to a holomorphic function $F$ on
>   $V$ for which*
>   $$f|V = f_0|V + f_1|V + \dots + f_{m−1}|V + F.$$

My attempt so far:
Because $V$ is a subset of $U$, any compact subset of $V$ must be compact in $U$ too. As such the series must be compactly convergent when limited to $V$. So we at least know that $\sum^\infty_
{n=m} f_n |V$ is compactly convergent on $V$. As such we that for every compact subset $K$ of $V$ we have that there is an $m(k)$ such that there is no pole in $K$ for any $n \geq m$, $f_n$. As such we have there is a maximum such $m$ in $V$, let's call this maximum $M$(This is the maximum $m$, such that there is no pole in any compact subset of $V$). Then we have that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=M} f_n$ is a series of holomorphic which converges compactly, so the limit function is holomorphic.
The rest of the series, that is $\sum^{M-1}_
{n=0} f_n |V$ converges because it's obviously a finite series. This resulting function is meromorphic, because it is a finite sum of multiple meromorphic functions.  Both limits are unique, so the resulting function $f = \sum^{M-1}_
{n=0} f_n |V + \sum^{\infty}_
{n=M} f_n |V$ is unique.

I'm however unsure of two things:
The first step, in which I assume that the series under consideration is compactly convergent on $V$, because it is on $U$. I'm also unsure whether it's correct to assume that I can just say that there is a maximum $m$, which removes poles from all subsets of $V$.

Comment: Of course if it converges compactly on $U$ it does on any open $V \subset U$. And you are given such a $m$, you don't need to find it. So yes on $V$ you have $\displaystyle F_k = \sum_{n = m}^{m+k} f_n$ is a sequence of holomorphic functions converging compactly on $V$, ie. $F_k \to F$ holomorphic on $V$